# How do I fetch data from a database, in MATLAB, with where clause using "and" operator?

Tags: mysql, matlab

```
conn= database ('test', '  ' , '  ');
sql = ' SELECT * from  table1 WHERE column1= value1 and column2 = value2';
results = fetch(conn, sql);
results
```

This piece of code gives output as follows
results = [ ]

Comment: I've never done a query in matlab, but your SQL itself is fine. Does it return results if you only use one of the predicates in the where clause at a time? Can you return a result by querying the database directly, using a tool like MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Did you confirm that the connection was made?  That is that `isempty(conn.Message)` is `true`?

Comment: update  your question add  a proper data sample and the expcted  result

Comment: The connection is fine. It, in fact, works fine when only one condition is specified. The only problem I face here, is that it doesn't give back anything when two conditions are specified with an "and".